# Datatable reload issue with ajax on small screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am using data table for my products view and I have Add to cart button at the end of every product to add the product in **CART** When i click on **Add to cart** button it adds the product to cart and button changes to **View cart** I am doing all this by using **AJAX** and through checking the domain id in cart array `$this->cart->contents();`
Here is the Ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : base_url+'home/add',
        data    : {id:rowId},
        beforeSend : function(){
            thisElement.html('<i style="font-size:1em;" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i> Add To Cart');
        },
        success : function(data){

            if(data == 'true'){
                $('.cart').notify("Domain Added To your Cart!" , "success");
                var total_item = $('.total_items').html();
                $('.total_items').html(parseInt(total_item)+1);
                if(windowSize >= 1200){
                    thisElement.closest('td').html('<a href="'+base_url+'home/view_cart" class="btn cartBtn">View Cart</a>');
                }else{
                    thisElement.closest('td ul li span:last-child').html('<a href="'+base_url+'home/view_cart" class="btn cartBtn">View Cart</a>');
                }
            }else{
                swal("Warning!", "Something Went Wrong!", "warning")
            }
        }
    });
});`
```

...It works fine at Desktop view but when view changes to small screen data table becomes responsive then If I click on **Add to cart** button first time It changes to **View cart** but If I click on `minus` sign of data table responsive icon child td disappear and view cart again changes to **Add to cart** button.
Where is the Problem?? how can It be solved??

[When click on plus button Child TD opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8BWU.png)

[When Clicked on Add to cart button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ff6.png)

Comment: update code with `click` event code too.. It seems something wrong with selector of `click` event.

Comment: @jagad89 It's working fine on desktop if something wrong with selector then it should also create problem on desktop

Comment: @jagad89 when in responsive view of data table I `click` on plus sign to open the child td where I have **Add to cart** button  and `click` on button it changes to **View cart** and then if I `click` on minus sign to hide the child td and again open the same child here comes **Add to cart** button I think It's issue with data table but don't know where the issue is.

Comment: I really need to look in detail.. do you have accessible URL ? Something wrong  happening JavaScript end that we really can't locate

Comment: Hey, I think datatable regenerating your whole row when your expand collapse.. I just did experiment. I opened this [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/column-control.html) and resize windows to mobile view. Expand any row and right click->inspect element and i collapsed that row. When I expand the row my changes not there. So datatable generating row again on expand.

Comment: After inspect element, i did some text change in html. When i collapsed and expanded it those changes were lost.

Comment: I am working on Local Server till I have no accessible URL. Yes I Have Same issue when i collapse and expand the html of that button again changed to **Add to cart** it should not be changed it should remain **View cart**.Where is the problem....???? Can you please help me out.